# returning calling class when using generic method in abstract class

Tags: java, generics, abstract

I have a strange problem, I'm not capable to understand. I guess It's because I'm not familiar with generics.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass <T extends AbstractClass <T>> {

   //...

   public <T extends AbstractClass> T genericMethod(){
   //do stuff
   return (T) this;
   }
}
```

No using this with a non-abstract Class

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass <MyClass> {
   //...
   public void anotherMethod() {
    //do other stuff
  }

}
```

So far more or less ok (maybe not ideal, but ok). Now the confusing part:

```
private MyClass stubWithMyClassAsReturnValue(){
   //more stuff
   return new MyClass();
}

public void test1(){
   MyCalss  myClass = stubWithMyClassAsReturnValue().genericMethod();
   myClass.anotherMethod();
   //---> works just fine
}

public void test2(){
   stubWithMyClassAsReturnValue().genericMethod().anotherMethod();
   //---> compiling error because AbstractClass does not know about anotherMethod(),
   // so genericMethod() returns AbstractClass and not MyClass
}
```

I guess there is some kind of implicit casting. How can I make the code more fluent and get rid of this superfluous "myClass"?  I'm pretty sure there's an obvisious mistake but I don't see it.

Comment: Your case is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344440/returning-calling-class-when-using-generic-method-in-abstract-class) under *More tricks with type parameters* heading, but the whole article is worth a read

Comment: @pafauk. thank you, but you linked to this page.:)

Comment: Aww heck, [here it is](http://madbean.com/2004/mb2004-3/). Should work now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```
//                                this T
//                                   v
public abstract class AbstractClass <T extends AbstractClass <T>> {
//     and this T
//         v
   public <T extends AbstractClass> T genericMethod(){
   //do stuff
   return (T) this;
   }
}
```

The two `T`s highlighted are different `T`s. The first `T` is the generic parameter of the class `AbstractClass`. The second `T` is the generic parameter of the `genericMethod`. These two `T`s are not related, and are independently inferred.

When you do this:

```
stubWithMyClassAsReturnValue().genericMethod()
```

The compiler knows what the first `T` is - `MyClass`, but it doesn't know what the second `T` should be, so it just uses the upper bound - `AbstractClass`. But `anotherMethod` is not available in `AbstractClass`, hence the error.

You likely only need one `T`:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass <T extends AbstractClass <T>> {

   public T genericMethod(){
       //do stuff
       return (T) this;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank mate! That fixed it.
Also your explanation was helpful. You are right, I mixed something up and there were some T's too much.